# Howto find the sum of values from posts' in Jekyll frontmatter

Tags: jekyll, github-pages

In each of my Jekyll posts, I have a number listed in the front matter:

```
---
minutes: X
---
```

The value is always different from post-to-post and I would like to find the sum of all the posts.

Not sure if this is possible or what the approach should be.

Thanks for any help in advance!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try:

```
{% assign total = 0 %}
{% for post in site.posts %}
  {% assign total = total | plus: post.minutes %}
{% endfor %}
{{ total }}
```